# Low Search results not showing all entries from a category

Tags: low-search

I have a search form composed of category select fields. When choosing a particular category (2 Bedroom / 2 Bath) the results page isn't showing all entries. But, when viewing the "all floor plans" page and selecting "Two Bedrooms" I can see every entry.

Any ideas on why the Low Search form wouldn't be showing every entry from a selected category? The form seems to work, as it shows *some* of the entries, but why wouldn't it show *all* entries?

Here's the search form where you can select the 2 Bedroom / 2 Bath option under "Number of bedrooms?":

http://l45living.com/floor-plans

Here's the page listing all "Two Bedrooms" entries:

http://l45living.com/floor-plans/all/two-bedrooms

Notice how there are many more entries displayed on the "all/two-bedrooms" page. Template code (edited for brevity):

```
{exp:low_search:form
  form_id="floor-plan-search"
  query="{freebie_3}"
  result_page="/floor-plans/search#floor-plans"
}
  <select name="category[]">
    <option value="">Show me all the options!</option>
    {exp:channel:categories
      category_group="1"
      show="not 4"
      style="linear"
    }
      <option value="{category_id}"{if low_search_category ~ '/\b'.category_id.'\b/'} selected{/if}>
        {category_name}
      </option>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
  </select>
{/exp:low_search:form}

{exp:low_search:results
  channel="units"
  orderby="title"
  query="{freebie_3}"
  require_all="category"
  sort="asc"
}
  ...results shown here...
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URI `/floor-plans/all/two-bedrooms` doesn't look like a Low Search query, and therefore the Results tag won't filter entries. It's looking like it works as designed. [This URL](http://l45living.com/floor-plans/search/eyJyZXN1bHRfcGFnZSI6IlwvZmxvb3ItcGxhbnNcL3NlYXJjaCNmbG9vci1wbGFucyIsImNhdGVnb3J5IjoiM3wyNyJ9#floor-plans) does seem to be showing the results you'd expect.

**Edit** Turns out there was another category selected so the form would filter by *both* categories rather than the one. Removing the other one solved the issue.

Comment: Correct, /floor-plans/all/two-bedrooms isn't a search query. That page is using a channel entries tag to show all entries marked with the "two bedroom" category. But, shouldn't the Low Search results page, as you linked to above, also show the same entries?

Comment: My confusion is that it seems selecting "two bedrooms" in the drop down on the search form should return all entries marked with the "two bedrooms" category, but it's not returning all of them. The entries displayed on the URL you linked to above should exactly match the entries displayed on the "/floor-plans/all/two-bedrooms" page, correct? Aren't they both in effect doing the same thing...showing all entries marked with that category?

Comment: That depends on how your template is set up. Are you expecting the Results tag to pick up on the /all/two-bedrooms segments? Because that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: No, I'm not expecting it to get any data from the other page. I'm just wondering why the search results don't show all entries. If you use the search form and only select "two bedrooms" it _does_ return some of the two bedroom entries, but not all of them. Shouldn't that form return _every_ entry categorized as "two bedroom"? I mention the "/all/two-bedrooms" page just because it's coded to show all entries marked "two bedroom", so it seems like both pages should show the exact same results.

Comment: The "all/two-bedrooms" page is working correctly. That is a channel entries tag showing the "two-bedrooms" category, and it displays the correct number of entries. The search results page for "two bedrooms" doesn't show the correct number of entries. Some entries are not displayed, even though they have been categorized as "two bedroom".

Comment: Can you share the channel:entries tag that you use for the all/two-bedrooms page that is showing the correct entries?

Comment: Sure. Also, we've checked the number of entries outputted. On the search results page for "two bedrooms" there are 19 entries returned. On the channel entries tag page for "all/two-bedrooms" there are 81 entries returned.

Comment: `{exp:channel:entries channel="units" cache="yes" category="5" disable="member_data|pagination" dynamic="no" orderby="title" refresh="60" sort="asc"}...{/exp:channel:entries}`

Comment: You know what, this isn't the right place for this. Please open a thread on my official support forums, along with version info, template code (use pastie.org for that) and other details: https://getsatisfaction.com/low